# Is there a way to initialize variables with erl?

Tags: erlang

I'd like to do things like L=lists, X=very_long_module_name. There's some modules I use a lot and I'd rather type X:function() than very_long_module_name:function(). The .erlang file seems to be able to run commands but it doesn't keep any variable assignments. For all know you can only use .erlang to add more things to path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could use macros? i.e. -DL=lists and then ?L:function() ?

Comment: I do. Macros in the erlang shell would be nice though. I've tried reading ulf wiger's post about it but didn't understand.